# PHP file upload not allowing format that is in allowed_types

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have an audio upload function that uploads music that the user selects.
However, some of the files shows they are in the correct format, but the uploader says that the file I am trying to upload is not correct.

My CodeIgniter config is as follows:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wav|m4a|wma';
```

I use the following to get the format of the audio:

```
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));
```

When I echo $ext out, it shows mp3, but the uploaded returns with this error:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

When I use an audio converter (I use Freemake) to convert the file to mp3 again, the uploader allows the file, so I am not sure if the file displays mp3 but is still the old format on the file system.

Any information/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

---

UPDATE

My PHP upload code looks like this:

```
    $entry_num = $this -> input -> post('entry_num');
    $location = $this -> input -> post('location');

    $foldername = "./music/$location";

    if (!file_exists($foldername))
    {
        mkdir($foldername, 0777, true);
    }

    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));

    $config['upload_path'] = $foldername.'/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wav|m4a|wma';
    $config['file_name'] = $entry_num.'.'.$ext;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

    $this -> load -> library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this -> upload -> do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $errors = array('error' => $this -> upload -> display_errors());
        $return = implode(" ",$errors);
    }
```

My View looks like this:
HTML

```
        <div class="control-group" id="load-music">
            <label for="grouping_style" class="control-label">Load MP3 Music</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" name="userfile">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
(function() 
    {
        var bar = $('.bar');
        var percent = $('.percent');
        var status = $('#status');
        var progressbar = $('#progressbar');

        $('#mp3form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit : function(data) {
                check = data[1].value;
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                progressbar.show();
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);

                if (percentComplete > 10)
                {
                    percent.show();
                }
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {                               
                if (xhr.responseText == '"success"')
                {                                       
                    $('#modal-footer-content').html("<button class='btn btn-default' onclick='cancel()'>Close</button>");
                    $('#modal-text').html('Music sucessfully uploaded, thank you.');

                    //Insert code to update table row with music play back

                    comp_code = '<?=$entry_details['location'];?>';
                    entry_num = <?=$entry_details['entry_num'];?>;

                    $('').postJsonCheck('comp/get_entry_details', {comp_code:comp_code, entry_num:entry_num},function(data){
                        var entry_details = data.entry_details;
                        var content = '<div style="float:left;padding-top:5px;"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="15" height="15"><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="<?=base_url();?>img/audioplay.swf?file=<?=base_url();?>comps/music/'+entry_details["location"]+'/'+entry_details["entry_num"]+'.'+entry_details["music_ext"]+'&auto=no&sendstop=yes&repeat=0&buttondir=<?=base_url();?>img/audiobuttons/green_small&bgcolor=0xffffff&mode=playstop"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high><PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent><embed src="<?=base_url();?>img/audioplay.swf?file=<?=base_url();?>comps/music/'+entry_details["location"]+'/'+entry_details["entry_num"]+'.'+entry_details["music_ext"]+'&auto=no&sendstop=yes&repeat=0&buttondir=<?=base_url();?>img/audiobuttons/green_small&bgcolor=0xffffff&mode=playstop" quality=high wmode=transparent width="15" height="15" align="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object></div><a href="#" onclick="edit_entry_music(\'<?= $entry_details['location']; ?>\', \'<?= $entry_details['entry_num']; ?>\');return false;" style="margin-left:5px; padding-top:15px;"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></a>';

                        if (entry_details.audio_status == 'Error')
                        {
                            content = '<div style="float:left;padding-top:2px; color: red; padding-right: 7px;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" data-original-title="Music to long! Length: '+entry_details.length_text+', Max Length: '+entry_details.max_length_text+'" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"></i></div>'+content;

                            var notification = {};
                            notification["type"] = 'error';
                            notification["text"] = 'Music added is too long!';
                            notification["title"] = 'Error';

                            show_notification(notification)
                        }

                        $('#edit_<?= $entry_details['entry_num']; ?>_music').html(content);
                        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'});
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    str = xhr.responseText;
                    var res = str.slice(4, -6); 

                    $('.music_upload_error').html(res);
                    $('.music_upload_error').show();

                    //alert('There was an error updating the music, please try again or contact the administrator. '+xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        }); 
    })();
```

Comment: post your full upload related code. Are you using CodeIgniter?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, Yes I am using CodeIgniter, my full PHP code has been added

Comment: what's your view part?

Comment: As you said if you convert your `mp3` files again to `mp3` file its working fine. it seems something wrong with your original file. use [pathinfo](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to get what actual type it detects on your raw mp3 file.

Comment: View code has been added to the question
This does happen to quite a lot of the music that people are trying to upload

Comment: I don't see `from` tag in your view. make sure you have attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form`, But I still strongly doubt on your raw file, because it works after you convert it.

Comment: The form tag is in the view file, its just a very long file, so I only copied the input field. I also think there is something with the file wrong, but too many people get this error, so there must be a better workaround to telling them all to reformat the music

Comment: can you give sample mp3?

Comment: sure, file can be downloaded here:
http://iserver.co.za/files/test_upload.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in codeigniter opens, mimes.php
and add this.

```
'mp3'  =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3', 'application/octet-stream')
```

> application/octet-stream means binary stream. A MIME attachment with
>   the content type "application/octet-stream" is a binary file.
>   Typically, it will be an application or a document that must be opened
>   in an application, such as a spreadsheet or word processor

Comment: Thanks! This was a quick and easy answer, do you perhaps mind explaining what the `'application/octet-stream'` means?

Comment: `application/octet-stream` means binary stream. It will also allow you to upload any `exe` file or any binary file. It is a dangerous solution as per me.

Comment: I tried uploading an exe file now, but my PHP code stops the file from being uploaded due to filetypes

Comment: So tell me which file types are allowed to upload?

Comment: @RickusHarmse I see, you may see the answer update. It says used for to open in specific application like `word` and `excel` so try with word file.

Comment: I will check with the mentioned file types

Comment: Seems to be working fine, these files are also not allowed, so all is in order